# solve this equation for $x$ : $y=x-6\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

solve for $x$ this equation :
$$y=x-6\sqrt{x}$$
I've tried raising everything to the power of two but it doesn't work 
$x$ shouldn't have two values.

Comment: Hint: Take the term with the square root to one side and square both sides. You'll get a quadratic equation.

Comment: You say that $x$ shouldn't have $2$ values.  First, this is an equation in $2$ variables so $x$ can take an infinite number of values.  But maybe you mean that $x$ should only take $1$ value for every value of $y$?  That would mean that this function is one-to-one.  Take a look at the plot -- it's not.  In fact I can easily see that $x=25$ and $x=1$ both correspond to the same $y$ value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ is surely a good tool:
$$
y=u^2-6u
$$
becomes
$$
u^2-6u-y=0
$$
which is quadratic in $u$. Remember, though, that $u\ge0$ by definition.

If $y>0$, the quadratic has one positive and one negative solution, so we can consider only the positive one:
$$
u=3+\sqrt{9+y}
$$
and $x=(3+\sqrt{9+y})^2$.

If $y<0$, the equation has two positive solutions provided the discriminant is positive; the discriminant is $9+y$, so we get the condition $y\ge-9$ and the two solutions are
$$
x=(3-\sqrt{9+y})^2,\qquad x=(3+\sqrt{9+y})^2
$$
For $y=-9$ there's actually just one solution.

In summary:

- No solution for $y<-9$
- One solution for $y=-9$, namely $x=9$;
- Two solutions for $-9<y<0$, namely $x=(3-\sqrt{9+y})^2$ and $x=(3+\sqrt{9+y})^2$
- Two solutions for $y=0$, namely $x=0$ and $x=36$;
- One solution for $y>0$, namely $x=(3+\sqrt{9+y})^2$

Comment: why is there only one solution for 0<y ?

Comment: @Lynn Since $u=\sqrt{x}$, you have $u\ge0$. However, an equation of the form $u^2+bu+c=0$ where $c<0$ has one positive and one negative roots (because the product of the roots is $c<0$): the negative root must be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} y = x-6\sqrt x & \iff (y-x) = -6\sqrt x \\ \\&\implies  y^2 - 2xy + x^2 = 36x\\ \\ &\iff x^2 - (2y - 36)x + y^2 = 0\end{align}$$

Now you can solve for $x$ using the quadratic equation (treat $y$ as a constant), but you'll want to check whether both solutions work, because by squaring, we may have introduced a solution that is not valid in the original equation.

$$x = \dfrac{(2y-36) \pm \sqrt{(2y - 36)^2 - 4y^2}}{2}$$

Now, it's just simplifying, and *remember to check both solutions*: Recall that $x\geq 0$ or else $\sqrt x$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

$$6\sqrt x=x-y$$
$$36x=x^2-2xy+y^2$$
$$x^2-(2y+36)x+y^2=0$$
$$x=\frac{2y+36\pm\sqrt{4y^2+144y+1296-4y^2}}2=y+18\pm6\sqrt{9+y}$$

Since $6\sqrt x\ge 0$ it must be $x\ge y$. Furthermore, $y\ge -9$.

For $y=-9$ we have $x=9$. For $-9< y\le0$ there are two solutions. For $y>0$ the solution obtained choosing '$-$' in $\pm$ implies that $x-y<0$ and it is not valid.

Comment: You should check for extraneous roots since you squared both sides.

Comment: i think you forgot the x in the third step .I believe 2y+36 by -x not -.Am i wrong?please answer

Answer (score 0):

$$
y= x-6\sqrt{x}
$$
$$
y = u^2 - 6u
$$
$$
u^2-6u - y = 0
$$
This last is a quadratic equation in the variable $u$.  You can use the usual formula or you can complete the square, thus:

$$
u^2-6u + 9 = y+9
$$
$$
(u-3)^2 = y+9
$$
$$
u-3 = \pm\sqrt{y+9}
$$
$$
u = 3\pm\sqrt{y+9}
$$
$$
\sqrt{x} = 3\pm\sqrt{y+9}
$$
$$
x = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute with $u=\sqrt{x}$ to get

$$ y=u^2-6u $$

$u$ can be expressed as

$$ u = \sqrt{x} = 3 \pm \sqrt{9+y} $$

from which you can express $x$ as

$$ x = \left( 3 \pm \sqrt{9+y} \right)^2 $$

Comment: If $y=7$, then you should get two solutions, $x=1$ and $x=49$. But $1-6\sqrt{1}=-5\ne7$.

Comment: $\sqrt{1}=\pm 1$ therefore $1-6(-1)=7$

Comment: Really? No, sorry, this is not in my math books. I always have $\sqrt{1}=1$.

Comment: Every positive number a has two square roots.

Comment: And you choose it at random which one? Please!

Comment: Under the most widely accepted convention, $\sqrt{x}$ denotes, for $x\ge0$, the unique non negative square root of $x$. Otherwise an expression such as $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ would denote *four* values and $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}$ three.

Comment: You have implicitly assumed positive $x$, which is not given. (You have also assumed real $y$, which is not given either.) If you take your example, i.e. $x=1$, you get $\sqrt{x}=\pm 1$, therefore $y=1-6(\pm 1)$, i.e. $y=7$ and $y=-5$. If you take $x=49$, you get $\sqrt{x}=\pm 7$, therefore $y=49-6(\pm 7)$, i.e. $y=7$ and $y=91$. I suppose this is clear. The positive root is sometimes implicitly assumed, but it is vague. This is already pointed out in some of the other solutions above.